# Did 79% of Greeks not have health insurance in 2013?

Tags: economics, healthcare, greece

The following [claim on recession in Greece](https://www.globalresearch.ca/eu-austerity-killing-greece-report-shows-suicide-infant-death-and-mental-illness-on-the-rise/5531637) is pretty shocking on its face, but also a little muddy:

> Citing OECD data of 2013, the BoG [Bank of Greece] underlines that 79% of the population in Greece was not covered with insurance and therefore without medical and medicine due to long-term unemployment, while self-employed could not afford to pay their social contributions.

Is that really the case that 79% of the Greek population was without health insurance in 2013? I find the number shockingly high given the EU goal of universal coverage etc. Greece, [in theory at least, had that already in 2012](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2012/06/heres-a-map-of-the-countries-that-provide-universal-health-care-americas-still-not-on-it/259153/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To quote [the source](http://www.bankofgreece.gr/BogEkdoseis/NomPol20152016.pdf#page=93) that article is citing for the claim:

> Σύµφωνα µε στοιχεία του ΟΟΣΑ (OECD 2015) για το 2013, µόνο το 79% του πληθυσµού στην Ελλάδα είχε ιατροφαρµακευτική κάλυψη.

Which, running through google translate, is in english:

> According to OECD data (OECD 2015) for 2013, only 79% of the population in
>   Greece had medical coverage.

The source for the Bank of Greece figure is OECD 2015. The following chart can be found in the [OECD Indicators, Health at a Glance 2015](http://apps.who.int/medicinedocs/documents/s22177en/s22177en.pdf#page=123):

[image: Health Insurange coverage from OECD 2015]

So, No, the opposite claim is made by their source, that 79% of the population *did have* health coverage.

<sub>[A link on how seriously you should take GlobalResearch articles.](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Globalresearch)</sub>

Comment: The following part about Greece from the OECD report might also be relevant: "However, since
June 2014, uninsured people are covered for prescribed
pharmaceuticals and for services in emergency departments
in public hospitals, as well as for non-emergency
hospital care under certain conditions (Eurofound, 2014)."

Comment: @Mad Scientist, this is true, but one should also consider the quality of the care and Health expenditure per capita. So, the numbers might be correct, but the real outcome, from first hand experience, is below average. Considering further that half a million educated people have migrated to other EU countries and elsewhere, among them a lot of doctors, the average "medical care know-how" has also dropped significantly.